# Facebook Connect integration: does it require flash?

Tags: flash, facebook

I'm integrating a **Flash-free** web site with Facebook Connect.

Loading it in Internet Explorer 7 (only in IE 7, not IE 6 nor IE 8) I get the famous IE information bar saying that the current web site requires the Adobe Flash Player and asks me if I want to install it.

If I remove the code needed to the Facebook Connect integration (some facebook-hosted javascript files), IE does not ask me to install Flash anymore.

As I've already said my web site does not require Flash at all and with IE 6, IE 8, Firefox or any other browser I'm not asked to install the Adobe Flash Player.

Is this normal? Does Facebook Connect require Flash? Does it need Flash only with IE7?

Comment: When you remove the necessary code, does that mean rolling back an entire set of integration changes, or just removing the single Javascript? Facebook Connect uses simple AJAX, from what I understand.

Comment: It means that I just remove the code necessary to the integration: some <script> tags (pointing to facebook-hosted javascript files).
In fact in one of these files it's definied a javascript object where a property of this object is in fact a swf file url.

Here's it's the snippet:
      `"xd_comm_swf_url":"http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z332D/hash/f4ua3qt1.swf"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to the same problem taken from the facebook developers forum:
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=51010

Comment: Here's the google cached copy of the same page: http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php%3Fid%3D51010